# Accessing Authorization Header

Tags: perl, dancer

How do I access the Authorization header of a request with Perl Dancer?

I have tested my client and it is successfully passing the `Authorization` header, but it does not appear in the `request->headers` hash. I can get it to show up by simply misspelling it or appending an `X-` in front but I'm making an API and would like to use the conventional header to pass the request signature for authentication.

Comment: Does it appear in the `%ENV` hash?

Comment: Are you looking for the header for your own information, or are you planning on doing your own authentication?  There's plenty of [Dancer plugins to handle auth](https://metacpan.org/search?q=dancer%20auth).

Comment: I'm made my own authentication with a HMAC, I feel it was simpler then using a plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like FastCGI strips the Authorization header, probably because [basic HTTP auth is hideously insecure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Disadvantages).  Not that sending in the username and password over a POST is any better.

From [Plack::Handler::FCGI](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aHandler%3a%3aFCGI#Authorization)...

```
Most fastcgi configuration does not pass Authorization headers to
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION environment variable by default for security reasons.
Authentication middleware such as Plack::Middleware::Auth::Basic or 
Catalyst::Authentication::Credential::HTTP requires the variable to be set up. 
Plack::Handler::FCGI supports extracting the Authorization environment variable
when it is configured that way.

Apache2 with mod_fastcgi:
--pass-header Authorization

mod_fcgid:
FcgiPassHeader Authorization
```

It's also mentioned as a caveat to [Plack::Middleware::Auth::Digest](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aMiddleware%3a%3aAuth%3a%3aDigest#LIMITATIONS).

Comment: Thanks, I just started using Dancer, so I was concentrating on it as the source of the problem.

Comment: Dancer is a relatively thin (compared to other web frameworks) wrapper around Plack.

Comment: The mod_fcgid directive is spelled 'FcgidPassHeader'

Comment: @dmaestro12 I copied from the Plack::Handler::FCGI docs. If you think they're in error, report them a bug. https://github.com/plack/Plack/issues

Comment: Spelling correction published in the latest version. https://github.com/plack/Plack/pull/584